# HTML: why is <sometag/> illegal for normal elements?

Tags: html

I've been reading up on the HTML5 spec. This has been in relation to use of font icons on my page.

In general, font icons tend to use the `<i>` tag or the `<span>` tag, but either way, because of the HTML spec, **you must supply an explicit closing tag**.

The following would for sure be shorter to send over the wire (incorrect HTML syntax):

```html
<span class="fa-user"/>
```

than would the following (correct HTML syntax):

```html
<span class="fa-user"></span>
```

Surely the HTML spec authors must have been concerned about speed too?  So my question is what is it that compelled the spec authors to say that [normal elements](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#elements-2) **cannot** be closed in the start tag as per
[HTML 5 standard, section 13.1.2.1](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#start-tags), item 6.

Just wondering what would have been the (negative) consequence if the HTML spec had allowed an empty [normal element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#elements-2) to be closed in the start tag?  For sure it would have saved the global internet of some bytes.

(Note: My question is not about WHAT is illegal or legal. I can read the specs or I can read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558119/are-non-void-self-closing-tags-valid-in-html5), but I've found no source to explain the *reasoning* which is what my question is about)

Comment: Self closing tags were never html anyway. The question would probably be whether it would be faster to download the extra few bits or make the browser processor be able to understand and parse these tags - in one of the answers in the duplicates, it states that browsers often had trouble parsing xhtml - which is probably why html5 got rid of it again.  Perhaps if you are worried about your html doc being too large, then there's an issue with how much info you are trying to display

Comment: From my experience, the amount of html doesn't affect the loading speed that much, it's what's displayed on the page (and how many resources like images and js files it has to download).  If you are still worried about the size, then you can use things like gzip compression to reduce it.  (also does this mean that you don't indent your html as spaces also take up a bit)

Comment: @Pete. I think the issue is compounded with the webcomponents standard. In that world it is quite normal to have fairly long tag names and it is common to define a custom element which isn't meant in any way to carry children (i.e. the element is always empty), because it is really all about the attributes. Yet, the HTML standard says such element _must_ have explicit closing tag. Perhaps a stupid question on my part, but if it would break nothing, then it seems to me that the HTML5 spec missed a golden opportunity to "go green" (save the world of some resources).